# Java: Method in another class not showing

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm trying to do some homework for a class in java
the portion I'm trying to do is create a new person in the homework.class which extends the .name class

name class

```
public class Homework extends Object implements Comparable<Homework> {

private int id;
private Name name;
private int section;
private Files files;
private int dateSubmitted;
```

...... part of the hwk class

```
public Homework(String first, String last, int section, int dateSubmitted){ //fix me
    this.id = nextAvailableUid();
    this.section = section;
    this.dateSubmitted = dateSubmitted;     
    this.name.Name(first,last); //error is here in the Name call telling me Name is not a method of Name
}
```

the error i get is in Name, its telling me to create a method Name in the Name class, which i know there is....
as seen exert from the name.class

```
public class Name implements Comparable<Name>{

private String Fname;
private String Lname;


    public  Name(String first, String last) {
    this.Fname = first;
    this.Lname = last; //init the name

}
 }
```

Comment: Of course `Name()` is not a method, it's a constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call the constructor with the `new` operator:

```
this.name = new Name(first,last);
```

Here's the [Java tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, im fairly new to constructors and creating my own methods

Comment: I've been programming in Jana for a fair while now, and I still forgot to add "new". Spent too long debugging this (assumed it was an issue with the visibility of the constructor). This is what happens when you spend time writing Python and Dart. -_-

Answer (score 0):

`this.name.Name(first,last);` looks at the name variable of the Homework class.  The name variable is an instance of the Name class.

The compiler then looks at the Name class for a method called Name that takes 2 Strings.  The method can be either an instance method or a static method.

Since there is no such method you get an error.

By convention methods start with a lower case letter, and classes start with an upper case letter.  This convention is very important as it helps you know what is what.  Each class also has at least one constructor (if you don't make one the compiler makes one for you).  The constructor has the same name as the class (part of the naming convention stuff).  Looking at the name class there is a constructor that takes two Strings.

To call a constructor you must use the "new" operator" eg. `this.name = new Name(first, last);`

Answer (score 0):

To add to the correct answer provided by @rgettman, you want to create a new `Name` object, and you do that with the constructor you already made: `public  Name(String first, String last)`

In Java (and a lot of other languages), you do that with `new`. So you simply say

```
new Name(first,last);
```

to create that object by passing in whichever strings are referenced by `first` and `last`.

But creating a new `Name` isn't enough; you need to be able to do stuff with it. So you assign it to the reference `this.name` so now `Homework` has a `name` member that references that newly created `Name` object in memory.

So with a `homework` object you could do something like `homework.getName().getFirst();`

When you wrote `this.name.Name(first,last);` that was like saying `Homework` has a `name` field with a method called `Name` that you're passing `first` and `last` to...which of course isn't what you meant.

It won't take long for you to learn how constructors work. Just keep at it!